# How to change bubble outline color using MessageKit in swift 4

Tags: swift4, messagekit

I tried to change bubble outline with below code but always showing black outline color.

```
func messageStyle(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageStyle {
    return .bubbleOutline(UIColor.red)
}
```

**Link Sample:** https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit

**Page:** ConversationViewController.swift

**Method:** messageStyle in extension ConversationViewController: MessagesDisplayDelegate

I have 2 users and I want to show bubble outline color different for each user. But with above code in the provided sample is not working.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I used the .bubbleTailOutLine method instead and that worked for me.

```
func messageStyle(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in  messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageStyle {
    let corner: MessageStyle.TailCorner = isFromCurrentSender(message: message) ? .bottomRight : .bottomLeft
    let borderColor:UIColor = isFromCurrentSender(message: message) ? .orange: .clear
    return .bubbleTailOutline(borderColor, corner, .curved)
}
```

[Bubble message with orange border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTFXv.png)